# Go - how to explicitly state that a structure is implementing an interface?

Tags: inheritance, go, interface, standards

Since Go puts a heavy emphasis on interfaces, I'm wondering how can I explicitly state that a structure is implementing an interface for clarity and errors checking in case some method is missing? I have seen two approaches so far, and I'm wondering which is correct and in accordance to Go specification.

Method 1 - anonymous field

```
type Foo interface{
    Foo()
}

type Bar struct {
    Foo
}
func (b *Bar)Foo() {
}
```

Method 2 - Explicit conversion

```
type Foo interface{
    Foo()
}

type Bar struct {
}
func (b *Bar)Foo() {
}
var _ Foo = (*Bar)(nil)
```

Are those methods correct, or is there some other way to do something like this?

Comment: [Effective Go: Interface checks](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_implements)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Method 2 is the correct one, method 1 you're just embedding a type and overriding its function. If you forget to override it, you will end up with a nil pointer dereference.

Comment: If you consider this a test (I do) you'd put the `var _ …` line into one of your `*_test.go` files. If the type isn't a pointer (e.g. if it's `Bar` that implements the interface rather than `*Bar`) you could use `var _ Foo = Bar{}`

Comment: I personally prefer to add it right above my types to make sure I don't accidentally break it, but ymmv.

Answer (score 7):

I have rarely needed to declare this, because there is almost always somewhere in my package where I am using the struct as the interface. I tend to follow the pattern of keeping my structs unexposed where possible, and providing them only through "constructor" functions.

```
type Foo interface{
  Foo()
}

type bar struct {}
func (b *bar)Foo() {}

func NewBar() Foo{
  return &bar{}
}
```

If `bar` does not satisfy `Foo`, this will not compile. Rather than add constructs to declare that the type implements the interface, I just make sure that *my* code uses it as the interface at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. In Go all interface implementations are implicit. You can check if a type implements an interface (and that is the most explicit it gets). If I recall correctly in a project I worked on, we just did some type asserts at the top of the package against the interfaces which the type implemented, and that is as close to explicit as it gets.

Comment: Indeed.  This was a deliberate decision on the part of the language designers.

Comment: [They mention the `var _` trick in the FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq#guarantee_satisfies_interface), so while they did decide not to include 'implements', they don't seem to be too against people hacking in checks.

Comment: @twotwotwo yeah there is value in it. The behavior developers are looking for is still there, whether or not your org/project uses it is up to you. In general, Go is progressive with what is part of the language and what isn't. I think most of their decisions have been quite good, this one included.

Answer (score 0):

The `var _` trick does not support generic constraints. You can only state "this certain specialized type implements the interface" but not "for all types satisfying a certain constraint, this composed type implements the interface". It is more convenient to do this with a function instead:

```
func _[T1 any, T2 comparable](v Foo[T1, T2]) Bar[T1] { return v }
```

This reads as

> For all types `T1`, for all comparable types `T2`, `Foo[T1, T2]` implements `Bar[T1]`.