# How to mark golang struct as implementing interface?

Tags: go

I have interface:

```
  type MyInterface interface {
  ...
  }
```

and I want to mark that my struct implements it.  I think it is not possible in go, but I want to be certain.

I did the following, but I think it results in an anonymous variable that implements interface.  Am I right?

```
  type MyStruct struct {
    ...
    MyInterface
  }
```

Comment: Go FAQ: [Why doesn't Go have "implements" declarations?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#implements_interface) and answer [How can I guarantee my type satisfies an interface?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#guarantee_satisfies_interface)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ensure a type implements an interface at compile time in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663003)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go - how to explicitly state that a structure is implementing an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753282/go-how-to-explicitly-state-that-a-structure-is-implementing-an-interface)

Comment: The accepted answer works for me for years.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In Go, implementing an interface is implicit. There is no need to explicitly mark it as implementing the interface. Though it's a bit different, you can use assignment to test if a type implements an interface and it will produce a compile time error if it does not. It looks like this (example from Go's FAQ page);

```
type T struct{}
var _ I = T{}       // Verify that T implements I.
var _ I = (*T)(nil) // Verify that *T implements I.
```

To answer your second question, yes that is saying your struct is composed of a type which implements that interface.

Comment: Thank you, that has been one of the best tips I have kept in my GO lang toolbox for years.

Comment: hi this may be an thread but, how do you implement design patterns if implementation will be like that? is it still possible>

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks a lot for this technique to check what methods are missing.